# What does Kanar taste like?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

What is Cardassian kanar supposed to taste like? Is it sweet or savory? I know there are many different versions of kanar, but what kind of flavor is it supposed to have?

Comment: 0
down vote
 

In my experience kanar usually has similar tratness to Klingon Boodwine, but a little more intense, and Yerbodness similar to, but a little less, than Romulan Ale.

Comment: No reason that Kanar would be any different from Earth beverages made of grapes. The diversity would vary enormously.

Comment: Possibly like fish juice; definitely not like root beer.

Comment: A lil like chicken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing in the TV series to indicate what it tastes like but several of the [EU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_spin-off_fiction) novels have a reasonable description: **It smells and tastes sweet and alcoholic but with heavy notes of rotten vegetables. To humans it's basically undrinkable.**

The best resource on offer is from the novel "[A Stitch in Time](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/A_Stitch_in_Time)" by Andrew J. Robinson (the actor who portrayed Elim Garak). Although none of the novels are considered 'canon', the fact that it was authored by one of the original show actors should give it some considerable weight:

> Kanar is a valuable if unreliable weapon I employ against this army.
>   The pills the Doctor gives me are a poor substitute.
>   ...
>   The Klingon commotion from the dabo table momentarily distracted me. **I took another sip of the bitter-sweet liquid.**

There's a description from the perspective of a human taster in "[Silent Weapons](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Silent_Weapons)":

> In front of La Forge was a squat tumbler of kanar, a syrupy alcoholic
>   treat from Dygan’s homeworld, Cardassia Prime. The chief engineer
>   picked up the glass and rolled it in a slow circle, testing the
>   viscosity of the fluid within; the kanar moved like industrial
>   lubricant. He took a whiff of it and wrinkled his nose in confusion.
>   **Its sweeter notes seemed enticing, but it was laced with a pungent
>   kick that threatened a less than benign drinking experience.**
>
> He and Dygan downed their drinks in single pours—then both men doubled
>   over as they sprayed the deck with spit-takes. **La Forge gagged and
>   smacked his tongue against the roof of his mouth in a futile bid to
>   rid it of the sickening taste of kanar**, and Dygan dropped his glass as
>   he coughed and gasped for air.

and from "[Terok Nor  : Night of the Wolves](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Wolves)"

> **Damar himself couldn’t stand the syrupy stuff**, never having developed
>   a taste for it, though he’d been known to take a glass in good company
>   for diplomacy’s sake.

and from [Rise Like Lions](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rise_Like_Lions) :

> Her verbosity made Damar smile. “You mean the people will throw us out
>   if we let the Klingons in. Thank you, Councillor, for that remedial
>   lesson in politics.” **He picked up a glass from his desk and sipped
>   kanar that was almost as sweet as the look on Gulal’s face was sour.**
>   Setting down the glass, he asked Temar, “How does Central Command
>   recommend we stop the Klingons?”

Comment: Great answer, but I'm a bit confused about the second quote, why doesn't Dygan like the Kanar if he's a Cardassian? On its own I'd take that to mean there was something wrong with it.

Comment: @MrLore I don't think there's a rule that they *all* like it. Not all Americans like Apple Pie.

Comment: Sounds like, maybe, sweet, alcoholic Worcestershire Sauce.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - All true Americans like apple pie, or at least pretend to. What are you, some kind of a commie?

Comment: I am a *false* American? WHAT?! Wait. I can live with that. I'm a *false* American. Yeah! Wait till the guys find out! "Hey, dudes, know how I'm not all UP IN THIS BIZNITCH on tha apple pie? I got news!!" Yeeeeah, boy! Thanks, Richie! (Still, I don't see how my name doesn't make me the ULTIMATE AMERICAN... Meat as a trademarked product? Yeah, I **AM** America.) -meat™

Comment: Sounds like the first time I tried durian fruit.

Comment: "Damar himself couldn’t stand the syrupy stuff" - Is this the same Damar who spent half a season of DS9 drunk off his ass on kanar?

Answer (score 6):

### I thought that its flavor depended on how it was brewed.

I have no definite answer for this, but I would suggest that as it's color changes its flavor would change as well. What it's flavor changes to, I would expect that that would be as spontaneous as its color.

[From Memory Alpha:](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kanar)

> Although not stated directly, **there were several types of kanar**. In
> TNG: "The Wounded" it appeared to be a light purple, transparent drink
> served in very small glasses.
>
> In DS9: "The Maquis, Part II" it was seen as the thick, black drink in
> characteristic bottles seen in many DS9 episodes.
>
> Then, in DS9: "The Wire" it was a blue, opaque drink in a different
> kind of bottle.
>
> In DS9: "The Way of the Warrior", it appeared differently again, this
> time it was an orange, opaque liquid, but served in the characteristic
> kanar bottles. After that, it finally changed back to the black, thick
> liquid seen for the first time in "The Maquis, Part II".
>
> According to an interview with Casey Biggs (Damar), Karo syrup was
> used for brown kanar to create the effect of a dark, thick liquid,
> which he actually drank. Property Master Joe Longo joked in an issue
> of Star Trek: The Magazine (Issue 4) that "... he was drinking so much
> he was getting weird, so we started using a thickened sugar-free
> pancake syrup."
>
> Damar's fondness for the spirit, first observed in "Behind the Lines",
> was introduced as a way to show an inner turmoil, essentially using it
> to drown out his conscience and justify an alliance he knows to be
> wrong – indeed, in "Strange Bedfellows", he looks at himself in the
> mirror and tosses the drink at his reflection just before helping Worf
> and Dax escape. (Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Companion)
>
> In "Behind the Lines", Kanar appeared as a much thinner liquid, akin
> to many Human beverages such as wine or spirits. This is in contrast
> to "Defiant" where Dukat was shown pouring the drink while being
> briefed by Sisko and Odo, where it appeared to have a thick,
> treacle-like consistency. The thinner liquid was of an older,
> expensive vintage, leading to the conclusion Kanar may thin out as it
> ages.
>
> **The strength of Kanar may also vary greatly**. In many episodes we see
> Cardassians drinking multiple bottles of it like it was wine, while in
> "Behind the Lines" Quark and Damar are both rendered drunk by sharing
> a single bottle; considering that they are a bartender and a soldier
> they're both expected to have great drinking stamina which suggests
> that this bottle of expensive Kanar had the strength of a hard liquor
> (which also explains the thinness of it as alcohol has a very low
> viscosity).

---

From this quote we can see that Kanar differs greatly from bottle to bottle.

Comment: @Richard I didn't quote the entire article. I quoted this portion, because it showed that Kanar has variety and since it has such variety the flavor of Kanar would have the same variety as well. I added that because I did not know of a canon answer.

Comment: @Richard It appears as if you answered the question. I'll wait to see if anyone thinks this adds to the post, before I delete it(for quality control).

Answer (score 0):

I had assumed from its viscosity that it might be a sap based liqueur gathered in the same way New England farmers tap maple sap to produce syrup, and some form of insect generated food. Perhaps like the byproduct of bees, just as honey is produced from the  secretions of insects through regurgitation of plant nectar. Likely in the process of fermentation spices of various kinds would be added to "tweak" the final product. Probably the same way wine acquires the subtle varieties of grapes, soil, temperature, and sun. Mead or honey wine, is an ancient alcoholic drink made from honey, and water through fermentation with yeast.